# Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot not booting, only boots with acpi = off

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, grub-efi, dual-graphics

My laptop cannot boot properly. If I turn off it right now, I ll only be able to boot it again if I use the APCI = off in parameters, how do I solve that ?

I m in dual boot ( actually triple )

SSD 240GB -> Windows 10
HDD 2.0TB internal -> Another Ubuntu install which I made only for testing
HDD 1TB external -> Installation of this actual Ubuntu. I want this to be my main Ubuntu.

I have an Nvidea GeForce 1050 graphics card.
I have Intel HD 620 integrated  graphics.

Some quick tests, I've tried nomodeset, but it didn't work.

I am running boot repair, so it made me this log
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kSVjYwXfpJ/ hopefully may help you help me..

Boot repair finished and generated this other paste bin https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pqvGRzVX8R/

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20200929_2120]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================



Warning: failed to translate partition name
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to sign-grub) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sdc2,
using the following options:        sdc1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups


/boot/efi added in sdc2/fstab
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Quantity of real Windows: 1
Mount sdc1 on /boot/efi
apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of sdc2
grub-efi-amd64-signed available

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-common-440
libnvidia-compute-440 libnvidia-compute-440:i386 libnvidia-decode-440
libnvidia-decode-440:i386 libnvidia-encode-440 libnvidia-encode-440:i386
libnvidia-extra-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-gl-440
libnvidia-gl-440:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-440 nvidia-compute-utils-440
nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-utils-440
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-efi-amd64-signed
DEBCHECK debOK
shim-signed available
Please type: sudo dpkg --configure -ansudo apt-get install -fynsudo apt-get purge -y grub*-common shim-signed
shim-signed available
linux-headers-generic available
linux-signed-generic NOT available (apt-cache policy  problem)
Then type: sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed os-prober shim-signed linux-headers-generic
GRUB is still absent. Please try again.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc2/etc/default/grub

==== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed os-prober shim-signed linux-headers-generic of sdc2 =====

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.4

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0003,0004,0000
Boot0000* ubu   VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7ac1c822-c071-419c-a842-735d0895936f,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,e96f734c-5b2b-45a5-a8b7-92b0dae77bac,0xe5370000,0x135f1b)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO

uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdc1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/
df /dev/sda2
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/sdb1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0000
Boot0000* ubu   VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7ac1c822-c071-419c-a842-735d0895936f,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sda3
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CurrentSession entry (sdc1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================
```

Comment: What happens if you disable ACPI in the BIOS?

Comment: I don't want to do that, cause I've read some issues by doing that and trying to run Windows 10, since I have it installed in my SSD